# Haxe garbage collection notification

Tags: memory-management, garbage-collection, haxe

I was wondering if there is a way to notify an object that it is beeing destroyed by the garbage collector? I'm guessing there is no such notification, but it would be super convenient if you point me towards something like that.

Thanks in advance,
Jery

Comment: I guess this depends on the target platform, I know not all platforms have events for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can't get that kind of notification on dynamic platforms for sure. But while targeting C++ you can write a custom finalizer for abstract types. This future is not well documented, but you can find more on that here: http://old.haxe.org/forum/thread/3395#nabble-td6613235

Answer (score 0):

Haxe does not provide garbage collection. Some platforms, like js provide garbage collection, but in that case, if it would have a notification, it won't be garbage collected, because of the reference counting, meaning there is no way to do this.